# Python3, how to install numpy on CentOS7..?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working with Python 3.8.7 on a computer having CentOS Linux release 7 (Core) operating system.

I have to install the numpy package.
I tried to follow these instructions, by running the command:

pip install numpy

Unfortunately, I got the following error:

ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Any idea on how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Use conda to manage python environments. It takes care of many package installation complications.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/20039, try to install another python version such as python 3.9 use pyenv to do that https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv